# Ember.js when use action want to render page current tap as well as new tap

Tags: ember.js

Edit, I am calling function edit and pass the id and get the details then render the edit page in same tab.Now, my problem was I unable to open in new tap when I try to open in new tab using clrl+click is not open. I want to open edit page current tab as well as new tap also..

Comment: without showing us some code there will be no much help I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want ctrl+click to open link in a new tab then the link needs to have an href set. This will happen automattically if you use the `{{linkTo}}` handlebars helper instead of `{{action}}`. If for some reason you need to use action instead then you will also need to manually bindAttr so that the href attribute is set. Have a look at the source for the linkTo tag to see how that can be done: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.7/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L323